# 'selectConnection' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Please help he for this code and this error

> Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be
>   called without a narrowing conversion:
>       'Public Sub New(selectCommandText As String, selectConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)': Argument matching parameter
>   'selectConnection' narrows from 'Object' to
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection'.
>       'Public Sub New(selectCommandText As String, selectConnectionString As String)': Argument matching parameter
>   'selectConnectionString' narrows from 'Object' to
>   'String'. F:\project\B-tech\FirstVBproject\LMSapp\LMSapp\book\updatecate.vb   89  23  LMSapp

```
Dim int As Integer
Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
Dim rdr1 As OleDbDataReader
'Dim dataadp As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
Dim cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand
Dim csearce As String
Dim cmdsearch As New OleDbCommand




Dim cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\project\B-tech\FirstVBproject\LMSapp\LMSapp\Library2.accdb")


Private Sub BunifuFlatButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BunifuFlatButton3.Click

    cnn.Open()

    Try

        Dim search As String = srctxt.text
        Dim dataT As New DataTable
        Dim dataS As New DataSet
        dataS.Tables.Add(dataT)
        Dim dataadp As New OleDbDataAdapter
        dataadp = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Category where ID like '%" & srctxt.text & "%'", cnn)
        'dataadp = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Category where ID like '%" & srctxt.text & "%'", cnnOLEDB)
        dataadp.Fill(dataT)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataT.DefaultView

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
    cnn.Close()
end sub()
```

Comment: What line of code caused the error? Temporarily comment out the Try...Catch...End Try to see what line is causing the error.

Comment: It appears that you have `Option Strict Off` and `Option Infer Off`.  That means that `Dim cnn = New OleDbConnection(...)` is declaring `cnn` as type `Object`.  Just specify the type in the same way as you have for all your other fields. Also, turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties.  You may or may not want to turn `Option Infer On` too.  I suggest that you learn what they both do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the data into datagrid view. You can edit my code below.

```
 'DGVforUSERNAME HA LOAD
    Dim ConnString As String = "provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\Users\rjimenez\Documents\QAdatabase.mdb"
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT Username, User FROM QAForHA where User='" & txtUser.Text & "'"
    Dim OleDBConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString11)
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet()
    Dim OleDbDataAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString11, OleDBConn11)
    OleDBConn.Open()
    OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "QAForHA")
    DgvUsernameHA1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("QAForHA")
```

Comment: The DataAdapter will open and close the connection for you but if it finds it open it will leave it open.

Comment: Connections are precious resources. It is not OK to leave one open.